# Setting one list static and the other dynamic

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two lists within a container. I want one of the lists to be static and the other to scroll. Right now I can get it to work somewhat but the list header for the second list scrolls with the list itself. No matter how I change the `overflow` - *scroll* or *auto* between divs it doesn't get me what I need.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list nearby">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
          <p>Nearby users</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="userlist">
        <User v-for="user in nearbyUsers" :key="user.UcpID" v-bind:user="user"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <div class="header all">
        <div class="title">
          <p>All online users</p>
        </div>
        <div class="searchfield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="..." v-model="search">
        </div>
        <div class="search">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="userlist">
        <User v-for="user in users" :key="user.UcpID" v-bind:user="user"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 100, 100);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 26px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header.all {
  background: rgb(218, 71, 71);
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: sticky;
}

.header i {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.userlist {
  background: rgb(255, 249, 249);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.searchfield input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}

.list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.list.nearby {
  min-height: fit-content;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/introzen/erhav0nz/4/

Is it also possible to set the `min-height` and `max-height` for `.list.nearby` and have it scale up to 5 listitems before it activates a scroll?

Comment: Can we update the html. In that case include a separate div that will contain all sub list values and provide scroll to that

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself

Comment: Sure @JerinJoseph. I've updated it Pete, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few changes - you can modify your *column flexbox*:

- you can use `position: sticky` to fix the header while scrolling lists,
- made each list a *column flexbox* and add `flex: 1` to the second list so that it will expand to the remaining space if available,
- add `min-height: 0` to the second list to reset the default `min-height: auto` for column flexboxes,
- add a `max-height` to your first list to restrict it to the height that corresponds to 5 items (I don't see any other way to do that),
- add `box-sizing: border-box` to include the `padding` in the `height`; have also reset `body` margin to zero,

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* added */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 100, 100);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 26px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky; /* added */
  top: 0; /* activate stickiness */
}

.header.all {
  background: rgb(218, 71, 71);
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.header i {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.userlist {
  background: rgb(255, 249, 249);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.searchfield input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}

.list {
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  min-height: 0; /* added */
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
  flex: 1; /* expand to fill remaining space */
}

.list.nearby {
  min-height:auto; /* changed */
  flex: 0; /* reset flex: 1 applied on list */
  max-height: 200px; /* beyond which scroll should happen */
}
```

```html
<div data-v-68be103e="" class="container">
  <div data-v-68be103e="" class="list nearby">
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="header">
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="title">
        <p data-v-68be103e="">Nearby users</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="userlist">
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzen</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">TYLAR5</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzan</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-v-68be103e="" class="list">
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="header all">
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="title">
        <p data-v-68be103e="">All online users</p>
      </div>
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="searchfield"><input data-v-68be103e="" type="text" placeholder="..."></div>
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="search"><i data-v-68be103e="" class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="userlist">
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzen</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">TYLAR5</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzan</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Rodneynoubs</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">frandunc</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Karinstoxy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">AlexisHal</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">HSKFairmietungDyeta</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">JeremyMew</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Robertgog</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">RodneyLig</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">root</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Davidfah</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Cathyneb</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Nekitbka</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Bobjex</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Melvinloazy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">BruceQuogy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Taghusod</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">zelebyaka</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">ultrasalvog</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Bennierak</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, had lunch! This works fine, however if the first list changes (etc. it has only two entries instead of one), it doesn't work anymore. If the first list expands, items are lost in the second list. if the first list shrinks, the second list doesn't reach the bottom of the page.

Comment: @introzen add `min-height: 0` to both `.list` and `.list.nearby`?

Comment: Nah it's still not expanding to fill the container when I remove an item from the top list :/

Comment: Nevermind, this solution doesn't work somehow.. I replied to the wrong answer. The answer from Xenio Gracias works however, just not fully

Comment: using `min-height: 0` it will not expand, but it solves the items getting lost... to expand, you can consider using  `flex-grow` property on the `.list` and `.list.nearby` - use a value of 1 for each if you want a 50-50 screen-share

Comment: I suck at explaining lol.. The first list should be static and the height of 1 whole item. At 5 items the first list should also become scrollable, since if it grows any larger you won't be able to use the second list. And the second list should expand to fill any other space in the container which isn't filled by the first list. Is that possible?

Comment: @introzen check out the updated answer and let me know how it looks now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have commented

```
/* .list {
  overflow-y: auto;
} */
```

and added

```
.dynamic-list {
  height: 305px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 100, 100);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 26px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header.all {
  background: rgb(218, 71, 71);
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.header i {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.userlist {
  background: rgb(255, 249, 249);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.searchfield input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}


/* .list {
  overflow-y: auto;
} */

.list.nearby {
  min-height: fit-content;
}

.dynamic-list {
  height: 305px;
}
```

```html
<div data-v-68be103e="" class="container">
  <div data-v-68be103e="" class="list nearby">
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="header">
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="title">
        <p data-v-68be103e="">Nearby users</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="userlist">
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzen</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">TYLAR5</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzan</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-v-68be103e="" class="list">
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="header all">
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="title">
        <p data-v-68be103e="">All online users</p>
      </div>
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="searchfield"><input data-v-68be103e="" type="text" placeholder="..."></div>
      <div data-v-68be103e="" class="search"><i data-v-68be103e="" class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-68be103e="" class="userlist dynamic-list">
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzen</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">TYLAR5</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">introzan</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Rodneynoubs</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">frandunc</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Karinstoxy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">AlexisHal</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">HSKFairmietungDyeta</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">JeremyMew</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Robertgog</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">RodneyLig</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">root</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Davidfah</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Cathyneb</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Nekitbka</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Bobjex</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Melvinloazy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">BruceQuogy</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Taghusod</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">zelebyaka</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">ultrasalvog</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div data-v-033c17a2="" data-v-68be103e="" class="user">
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userinfo">
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="name">Bennierak</p>
          <p data-v-033c17a2="" class="char">as </p>
        </div>
        <div data-v-033c17a2="" class="userdetails"><i data-v-033c17a2="" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This now works, but how do I expand the lower list automatically to fill the container height, depending on the number of entries in the first list? https://jsfiddle.net/introzen/hcyrjv51/1/

Comment: i didn't get you.. if the height of the top list increased then the height of the container should also increase?

Comment: I saw now that I had an error in the html. On my page, the container has a parent with fixed height.

Comment: @introzen then can you please mark this as answered. so others don't get confused. thanks